# Hi, could someone explain what use-dependence is? And does it differ from one drug type to another? For instance anaesthetics vs anti-epileptics?

Tags: pharmacology

I may have understood it incorrectly but I read that in case of local anaesthetics, the use dependence is such that more the number of open sodium channels, more the number of drug molecules entering, leading to increased inactivation. Whereas in the case of antiepileptics, the drugs bind to the sodium channels in its inactivated state and decreases number of available sodium channels to allow AP to pass through. So what exactly is use dependence?

Comment: It's best to support your question with things you've read (and it's an expectation on this site to provide evidence of prior research before asking) - where are you reading about use-dependence in local anesthetics? Where are you reading about it with anti-epileptics? Cite sources, use short quotes if relevant: what specifically are these sources saying and where does the uncertainty arise?

Comment: I would think that this question is more suitable for SE Medical Sciences (after taking heed of Bryan’s remarks).